# Helper method for pushing UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to **instantiate - set - push** a view controller using a helper method like this but in the same time avoiding downcasting?

```
func pushController(id: String, setup: (_ vc: UIViewController) -> ()) {
  if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) {
    setup(vc)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }
}

// usage
pushController(id: "Cars") { vc in
  (vc as! CarsVC).brand = "BMW"
}

// ...want to avoid downcasting
vc.brand = "BMW"
```

Comment: There is no way around casting, since `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` will always return an object of type `UIViewController`, you either cast in your `pushController(id:)` method or cast the return value of `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` and have specialized helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid downcasting, but you can make it less painful:

```
func pushController<VC: UIViewController>(id: String, setup: (_ vc: VC) -> ()) {
  if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as? VC {
    setup(vc)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }
}

// usage
pushController(id: "Cars") { (vc: CarsVC) in
  vc.brand = "BMW"
}
```

Not tested, so there might be minor issues.

EDIT: I should note that this fails silently when the wrong type is used with an ID. You may want to add an `else` after the `if` to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant solution I could think of is using generics, like this (playground)-example:

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    func pushController<T:UIViewController> (id: String, setup: (_ vc: T) -> ()) {
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as? T {
            setup(vc)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }

}

class ViewControllerA:UIViewController {}

class ViewControllerB:UIViewController {
    var bValue:Int = 0
}

let vcA = ViewControllerA();

vcA.pushController(id: "B") {
    (vc:ViewControllerB) in
    vc.title = "view controller b"
    vc.bValue = 42;
}
```

I would have preferred calling `pushController` with an explicit generic type, but unfortunatley this is not supported by Swift 3:

```
vcA.pushController<ViewControllerB>(id: "B") { // Error: cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
    vc in
    vc.title = "view controller b"
    vc.bValue = 42;
}
```